# WCF Data Services client not working on WP8 emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2012, emulation, wcf-data-services, windows-phone-8

Just tried an App that works with WP7 emu and VS 2010, called a data Service and worked but tried with WP8 SDK in VS 2012 and it's not working on emu and breaks with "Not Found" error: An exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException' occurred in System.Data.Services.Client.DLL but was not handled in user code

Someone have found this too?

Comment: never mind, it's just that because of the network configuration in the new emulator I supose, then localhost is not directing to the local machine, so I used my machine name instead of localhost for the Service url

Answer (score 1):

Sounds much to me like your problem is the emulator not having any internet connectivity. I'll recommend you remove the emulator from the Hyper-V list, use a Ethernet cable to your computer, and then restart your project.

Comment: In the emulator I can browse websites so I think it has Internet, I have tried to play with the Hyper-V settings of the emulator now that you mention it but had no luck